# Error in Meteor future.js line 267

Tags: javascript, meteor, webstorm, typeerror

First post here.

I am getting an error message saying an exception is being thrown at line 267 of future.js. I am new to meteor and am not sure where this type error is occurring.

```
W20170124-09:28:51.327(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/austinheitmann/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.f6mvc8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267
W20170124-09:28:51.327(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20170124-09:28:51.327(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20170124-09:28:52.249(-7)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
W20170124-09:28:52.250(-7)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.imports.startup.server.dataLoader.js.Loader.loadSuccessPaths._this7 (imports/startup/server/dataLoader.js:576:26)
W20170124-09:28:52.250(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20170124-09:28:52.250(-7)? (STDERR)     at Loader.loadMilestoneGroups (imports/startup/server/dataLoader.js:568:29)
W20170124-09:28:52.251(-7)? (STDERR)     at Loader.load (imports/startup/server/dataLoader.js:34:14)
W20170124-09:28:52.251(-7)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.imports.startup.server.app.js.Meteor.methods.informLogout (imports/startup/server/app.js:306:16)
W20170124-09:28:52.251(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/austinheitmann/trubyv/austin/austinpaths/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:290:5
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: you need to show your code.

Comment: It's probably because you placed a function call in your client directory that can only properly run server side.